# How can I create different ports on Apache VirtualHosts

Tags: apache, port, plesk

I'm trying to create VirtualHost for a different port number with below code, but when I try to access that port number "domain: port" I receive "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error on browser.

**Steps, what I do**

1. First editing http.conf, created for the related domain via Plesk
2. I am writing these codes
3. Restart Apache

   - Also I add that port number on httpd.conf. (Listen: port) but at this point I receive "Internal Server Error"

**What do I use:**
Plesk 12,
Apache/2.2.15 (Unix),
Ngnix (Reserve proxy)

```
<VirtualHost IP:8324>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/httpdocs"
        ServerName "domain:8324"
        ServerAlias "www.domain.com"
        ServerAlias "ipv4.domain.com"
        UseCanonicalName Off

   <Directory /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs>
       DirectoryIndex index.php
       Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +Includes
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I missing? Thank you

Comment: Did you add a Listen statement in ports.conf ? IIRC that has to have whatever ports a virtualhost is bound to listed in it

Comment: This is not for IRC. Port number can be different. I'm doing this for call different pages on different ports.

Comment: Since you are using Plesk if you manually edit the httpd.conf file, on the next Plesk update, most probably, it will overwritten.

Comment: It's not a problem, I just want it to get work.

Comment: @OrkanKöylü - sorry, should not have abbreviated.  If I Recall Correctly.  I do know the difference between internet relay chat and what apache and other http daemons do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that using a custom template for a specific vhost.
You should check these two links. The might put you on the right track:

https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/advanced-administration-guide-linux/virtual-hosts-configuration/changing-virtual-hosts-settings-using-configuration-templates/example-changing-default-apache-ports.68800/

https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/advanced-administration-guide-linux/virtual-hosts-configuration/changing-virtual-hosts-settings-using-configuration-templates.68693/

Just so you know, any manual changes that you do in the httpd.conf file (from a ssh console for example, at the next plesk update or when you add/delete an account, they will be overwritten since Plesk is regenerating the httpd.conf file)

Comment: I have editing "domain.http.conf", not directly httpd.conf

Comment: As I was saying. please do read Plesk documentation from the links I have provided. I am pretty sure they offer the answer you are looking for. I do not have a plesk server at hand to test the configuration so I can't really provide  step by step instructions...

Comment: In Plesk documentations, they just telling about creating custom domain.httpd.conf but I already do that, I need to know how can I open a second port for a domain. For example, Plesk CP can be accessed via 8443 port number how can they redirect this port number to another path.

Comment: You will find that info in the documentation as well. There is a special section where they tell you exactly how to change the default 8443 port to another port

Comment: I don't want to change Plesk's default port number I want to create my own for my domain. I want to serve different pages on different port numbers.

Comment: Did you allow that port number in the Plesk firewall?

Comment: I don't use Plesk's firewall. Also, server has no firewall. Apache responding port number but connection refused.